# How To Create Custom Route in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have an Area named Admin with a model named CMSPage.  My controller is named CMSPagesController.  I would like to create a custom route so I can use simply Page instead of CMSPage, so I thought by creating the following custom route, it would work but nope:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "AdminPages",
    "Admin/Pages/{action}/{id}",
    new { controller = "CMSPages", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Could someone please lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Did you put this code before the default route?

Comment: Yes, and the goal is to keep my internal class object names just that, internal.  Then, for my application, I wouldn't want that internal name, so I wanted to rename it via custom route to simply an application-friendly name (CMSPage == Page).  I see Neeraj's answer below but I think I tried that same example and it didn't work.  I'm going to give it another try and report back my findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oops on my part.  I forgot that there was the area registration process that happens as well.  The issue is that I want to access this controller from the area in which I created it (Admin).  So, the custom route registration has to happen there.  Not in my RouteConfig.cs (see below).  Thanks for the response Neeraj, you're answer is not wrong, just not correct for my question which was in regards to an area.

```
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace WebApplication1.Areas.Admin
{
    public class AdminAreaRegistration : AreaRegistration 
    {
        public override string AreaName 
        {
            get 
            {
                return "Admin";
            }
        }

        public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            // This is where the custom route has to be registered for me to access
            // it from my area.
            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_pages",
                "Admin/Pages/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", 
                      controller = "CMSPages", 
                      id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );

            context.MapRoute(
                "Admin_default",
                "Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;
namespace MvcApplication1
{
public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Blog",                                           // Route name
            "Archive/{entryDate}",                            // URL with parameters
            new { controller = "Archive", action = "Entry" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Default",                                              // Route name
            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",                           // URL with        parameters
            new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = "" }  // Parameter defaults
        );
    }
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
}
```

}

The order of the routes that you add to the route table is important. Our new custom Blog route is added before the existing Default route. If you reversed the order, then the Default route always will get called instead of the custom route.

The custom Blog route matches any request that starts with /Archive/. So, it matches all of the following URLs:

/Archive/12-25-2009

/Archive/10-6-2004

/Archive/apple

The custom route maps the incoming request to a controller named Archive and invokes the Entry() action. When the Entry() method is called, the entry date is passed as a parameter named entryDate.